# Catkinising package- Unable to include a header file from another package- Indigo

Tags: catkin, include, find-package, header, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have **three packages** in the same workspace called:

**art_msgs** (contains messages in art_msgs/msg folder)

**art_common** (contains some nodes in *art_common/srcfolder* which depend on messages from *art_msgs*; and *art_common/include/art* folder)

**art_map** (contains nodes in art_map/src which depend on art_common)

I am able to successfully compile art_msgs and art_common. However the nodes of art_map include header files from **art_common/include/art** which are not included when I catkin_build the workspace.

Based on another post, I have tried installing the header file, by adding the following in CMakeLists.txt of art_common

```
install(DIRECTORY include/art/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```

which results in the following error:

```
In file included from /home/amogh/rosws2/src/art_map/src/DrawLanes.cc:2:0:
/home/amogh/rosws2/src/art_map/include/art_map/euclidean_distance.h:20:25: fatal error: art/epsilon.h: No such file or directory
 #include <art/epsilon.h>
```

Also when I add the following, in CMakeLists.txt of art_map:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS art_common)
```

The following error arises:

```
Errors     << art_map:check /home/amogh/rosws2/logs/art_map/build.check.044.log                          
CMake Error at /home/amogh/rosws2/devel/share/art_common/cmake/art_commonConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findart_msgs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "art_msgs",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "art_msgs" with any
  of the following names:

    art_msgsConfig.cmake
    art_msgs-config.cmake
```

Other required dependencies have been resolved in package.xml and CMakeLists.txt. You can see the complete code [here](https://github.com/amogh112/mappingRNDF/tree/master/src).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272610/catkinising-package--unable-to-include-a-header-file-from-another-package--indigo/) by [Amogh Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/27274/amogh-gupta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-09**:
Btw: may I suggest a title change? The problem here is that the catkinisation of your pkgs is incomplete/incorrect. Whether or not the headers can be included successfully remains to be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I'm not mistaken, the packages you are referring to were rosbuild packages.

You converted them to Catkin, but if I look at [art_msgs/src/art_msgs/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/amogh112/mappingRNDF/blob/3a08e000e10ed5c42496a81bd909c0af8db33385/src/art_msgs/CMakeLists.txt), I don't see a `catkin_package(..)` statement anywhere.

That will cause the error you included in your OP.

If you haven't already, please check the [catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) page on the wiki. And check the [catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) on how to deal with things like message and service dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amogh Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/27274/amogh-gupta/) on 2017-10-09**:
Yes, I am attempting to catkinise rosbuild packages, I added the following based on your suggestion:

```
catkin_package(
    DEPENDS
    CATKIN_DEPENDS message_generation nav_msgs geometry_msgs std_msgs sensor_msgs
    INCLUDE_DIRS
    LIBRARIES
)
```

Still the same errors.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-09**:
Order matters for these things. Please remove your `build` and `devel` directories, read the pages I linked to carefully, read [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) also carefully and try again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-09**:\

> ```
> catkin_package(
> ```

```
    DEPENDS
    CATKIN_DEPENDS message_generation 
    ..
```

That won't work, and is also described in the pages I linked to: the `CATKIN_DEPENDS` should be `message_runtime`.

**Comment by [Amogh Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/27274/amogh-gupta/) on 2017-10-10**:
I made the change suggested and went through the links in my understanding, however still unable to build the package, it is unable to find the header files from art_common/include/art.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
It would help if you could push your current state to your github repository.